# JSF: No validator could be found for type when adding a converter and a validator to a p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm currently encountering the problem specified above when trying to add a converter and a validator to a single field. I know how these 2 works because I've used them before, but this is the first time I've tried both of them on a single field. Here are my codes:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="bussProgram"
    value="#{signupWizardBean.subscription.businessProgram}">
    <f:converter binding="#{membershipProgramConverter}"></f:converter>
    <f:validator binding="#{dropdownValidator}"></f:validator>
    <f:selectItems value="#{signupWizardBean.membershipPrograms}"
        var="plan" itemValue="#{plan}"
        itemLabel="#{plan.description}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Converter

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class MembershipProgramConverter implements Converter {
    @PersistenceContext
    private transient EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(value) || value.equals("0"))
        return null;

    return em.find(MembershipProgram.class, new Long(value));
}

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        MembershipProgram mp = (MembershipProgram) value;
    return mp.getId() != null ? String.valueOf(mp.getId()) : null;
    }
}
```

Validator:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class DropdownValidator implements Validator, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -456545939475878299L;

    @Inject
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    log.debug("[dropship-web] validating value={}", value);
    if (value == null) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                bundle.getString("error.requiredField"),
                bundle.getString("error.requiredField"));
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        facesContext.addMessage("promoCode", msg);

        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
}
}
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CRM_MEMBERSHIP_PROGRAMS", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "code" }))
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CRM_MEMBERSHIP_PROGRAM_SEQ")
public class MembershipProgram extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7796298586810386239L;

    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = true)
    private String description;

    public MembershipProgram() {

    }

    public MembershipProgram(long id, String description) {
        setId(id);
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((code == null) ? 0 : code.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MembershipProgram other = (MembershipProgram) obj;
        if (code == null) {
            if (other.code != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!code.equals(other.code))
            return false;
        if (description == null) {
            if (other.description != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!description.equals(other.description))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that on debug: both the MembershipProgramConverter.getAsObject/getAsString, DropdownValidator.validate methods are called.

I also found out that with or without selected item from the dropdown list, I'm encountering:

```
.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: com.czetsuya.models.membership.MembershipProgram.
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: com.czetsuya.models.membership.MembershipProgram.
```

Comment: try <f:validator validatorId="#{dropdownValidator}" />

Comment: Hi, changing to validatorId throws: javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression Error: Named Object: com.czetsuya.dropship.jsf.validators.DropdownValidator@5e118311 not found. I think that is for FacesValidator approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out the problem, I've added @Size annotation on the target entity, just removed the @Size:

```
@Size(max = 25)
@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "BUSINESS_PROGRAM", nullable = false)
private MembershipProgram businessProgram;
```

When I removed the @Size, the problem was solved but I have encountered a new one, on submit it the form always throw:

```
Validation Error: Value is not valid
```

To fixed the Value is not valid, make sure that you have properly implemented Model.equals method. My fault was that I rely on eclipse generate hashcode and equals feature, I failed to notice that it calls the equals method from my BaseEntity.

Comment: OK - but why does removing @Size work?  What happens if you still want to use @Size?